# ob_start() is printing outputs without ending of ob_get_flush()

Tags: php, ob-start

Is there anything i am doing wrong in the following code.

Ob_start should buffer the output right and it should not print it before you flush. But it is doing that

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
ob_start();
for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++ ){
    echo "I am fine </br>";
}
?>
```

I am getting the output **"i am fine"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's flushed when the script ends, so of course you will still get the output, it just won't be sent while the script is still running.

Answer (score 3):

You should do something with the buffer at the end of your script.

E.g. get the contents with `ob_get_contents()` and clear it with `ob_end_clean()`, otherwise it is flushed at the end.